# Getting free() invalid pointer error, when reading file and string joining

Tags: c

So I have this function

```
char    *read_file(int fd)
{
    char    *str;
    char    *buffer;
    int     bytes;

    buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 101);
    if (!buffer)
        return (NULL);
    bytes = read(fd, buffer, 100);
    while (bytes != 0)
    {
        if (bytes == -1)
        {
            free(buffer);
            return (NULL);
        }
        buffer[bytes] = '\0';
        str = ft_strjoin(str, buffer);
        bytes = read(fd, buffer, 100);
    }
    free(buffer);
    return (str);
}
```

It calls this function ft_strjoin

```
char    *ft_strjoin(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    char    *str;

    if (!s1 && !s2)
        return (ft_strdup(""));
    if (s1 && !s2)
    {
        str = ft_strdup(s1);
        free(s1);
        return (str);
    }
    if (!s1 && s2)
        return (ft_strdup(s2));
    if (!s2[0])
        return (s1);
    str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (ft_strlen(s1) + ft_strlen(s2) + 1));
    if (!str)
        return (NULL);
    ft_memmove(str, s1, ft_strlen(s1));
    ft_memmove(str + ft_strlen(s1), s2, ft_strlen(s2));
    str[ft_strlen(s1) + ft_strlen(s2)] = '\0';
    free(s1);
    return (str);
}
```

The reason why I free s1 is because the previous string will be malloced so I free the previous string and return the new string. How ever it's causing an error free() invalid pointer. If I remove the `free(s1)` at the end of `ft_strjoin` the error goes away but I need to free the previous string, so what do I do. `ft_strdup` just mallocs a new string, duplicates the argument, and copies it to the new malloced string and returns the new malloced string. `ft_memmove` does what `memmove` does.

Comment: In `read_file` you never initialize `str` before it's passed to `ft_strjoin` for the first time.

Comment: IMHO, `ft_strjoin` could be much simpler if you only used realloc and strcat... Anyway using uninitialized variables is known to invoke UB and `str` is not initialized in `read_file`. But for performance reasons, I would try to keep the size of str instead of computing it over and over...

Comment: Yes but I checked inside the `ft_strjoin` function, if s1 is NULL, no?

Comment: Ok I see so I had to set str = NULL; inside the `read_file` function. Tysm

Answer (score 1):

1. Your function can be reduced to:

```
char  *read_file(int fd)
{
    char *str = NULL;
    struct stat st;

    if(fstat(fd, &st) != -1)
    {
        str = malloc(st.st_size);
        if(str)
        {
            if(read(fd, str, st.st_size) != st.st_size)
            {
                /* error handling */
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

2. `ft_strjoin` is much too complicated. You should not free any memory in this kind general function. Use `memcpy` (or your version) to copy.

```
char    *ft_strjoin(const char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2)
{
    char *str;
    size_t s1len = s1 ? ft_strlen(s1) : 0, s2len = s2 ? ft_strlen(s2) : 0;
    size_t newsize = s1len + s2len + 1;

    str = malloc(newsize);
    if(str)
    {
        if(s1) ft_memcpy(str, s1, s1len);
        if(s2) ft_memcpy(str + s1len, s2, s2len);
        str[newsize - 1] = 0;
    }
    return str;
}
```